# In Eclipse IDE for C/C++, what key command selects the current word?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Title says it all. Mouse users can double-click. I can't find the equivalent for keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Select Enclosing Element* **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>** to select a word  while the cursor is on it.

Press again to select the next bigger connected part. If you selected to much you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to make the selection smaller.

Comment: Thanks. Alt+Shift+Up works in some cases but not others e.g. https://i.imgur.com/hTCKS8b.png , https://i.imgur.com/gZzo2ta.png .

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

- `Ctrl + LeftArrow` to navigate to the beginning of the current word (if not already at the beginning)
- `Shift + Ctrl + RightArrow` to select to the end of the word

Comment: That's my current nearest workaround too. Interestingly it is not equivalent to double-click in some cases e.g. double-click in the left side of the left bracket here pig=vec3(.15,.15,.15)*2; selects .15,.15,.15 (omitting the bracket) https://i.imgur.com/g2lv2aA.png . The nearest keyboard equivalent is seven command of three types.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Yeah, there are a lot of edge cases around the notion of a "word" when it comes to punctuation...

Comment: These aren't edge cases around the notion of word. These are failures of keyboard and mouse to agree on a common notion of word.

Comment: @ChrisJJ. Yes, agreed. Architecturally, what's happening here is that the Eclipse Platform exposes a mechanism for language-specific plugins to customize the behaviour of double-click select, but not of keyboard-based word boundary navigation. You could consider [filing an Eclipse Platform bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform) to improve the customizability here.

Comment: Do you think that's the cause of this failure? I'd hoped double-click select granularity was independent of input device.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: The cause of the difference in behaviour between double-click and ctrl+arrow is that CDT customizes the behaviour of the former but not the latter, because there is no customization point of the latter. There is a [recent bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558508#c10) with some relevant discussion.

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen that... inc. the "no, there is no language-specific logic for it" with which your "a mechanism for language-specific plugins to customize the behaviour" does not accord, ISTM.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: There are 3 behaviours in question: (A) the initial selection on double-click, (B) how to expand the selection when dragging after double-click, and (C) how to expand the selection via `Shift+Ctrl+Arrow`. The platform currently only exposes a customization point for (A).

Comment: Are you suggesting customisation of (A) is responsible for some or all of the discrepancy between double-click and your "I would do" keyboard solution?

Comment: @ChrisJJ Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Thanks. How can I verify that? My attempt to uninstall all the plugins removes eclipse.exe (!). My attempt to remove just those with C/C++ in name is barred with ""C/C++ Development Tools" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled."

Comment: @ChrisJJ Perhaps just open a `.txt` file in Eclipse and check the double-click select behaviour there?

Comment: @ChrisJJ Even easier: you can open your C/C++ source file in the plain text editor via "right click file in Project Explorer --> Open With --> Text Editor". I just tested now, and I definitely see differences in double-click select behaviour between the C/C++ editor and the text editor.

Comment: I wrote: "double-click in the left side of the left bracket here pig=vec3(.15,.15,.15)*2;". Correction: double-click in the left side of the right bracket here pig=vec3(.15,.15,.15)*2;

Comment: Thanks - verified. And my test results C in Text Editor fit with your explanation. Do you know any documentation for the mouse select behaviours?

Comment: @ChrisJJ The closest thing I could find is [this source code comment](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/text/CWordFinder.java#n34).